# Slider events not working on jqm 1.8.2

Tags: javascript, jquery-mobile

I have a working JSfiddle of a Jquery Mobile slider which alters the proportions of a div.

I want to use it with a newer version of Jquery Mobile (1.8.2) but it's not working. Can anyone help?

```
<div data-role="fieldcontain">
<input type="range" name="slider" id="slider" value="60" min="0" max="100" /></div>
<div id="proportion" style="border:1px solid #ccc; width:150px; height:150px;" /></div>​
<script>$("#slider").change(function() { sliderValue = $(this).val(); $("#proportion").width(sliderValue*3); $("#proportion").height(300-sliderValue*3); });​ </script>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/gsjBC/

Answer (score 0):

The jquery mobile version you are using is an old version(1.0b2) while the current stable version is 1.2 . jquery 1.8.2 might be incompatible with jquery mobile 1.0b2.So you might have to upgrade to the latest version of jquery mobile.Here is your fiddle with jquery mobile 1.2 used instead of 1.0b2.

http://jsfiddle.net/gsjBC/1/

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.2.0/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.css" />
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.2.0/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: That fiddle was using the old version of jqm, it's true but my mobile app is using jqm 1.2 and still doesn't work. Any ideas? - here is a link to my html http://www.spiesandflyders.co.uk/test.html